# Re-rendering Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have something like this in my .vue template:

```
<plasmid id='p1' plasmidheight="800" plasmidwidth="800" v-bind:sequencelength="sequenceLength">
```

I use Vue.js to manipulate the sequencelength attribute and then add a piece of code that manipulates that to create an svg element.

Now when `sequenceLength` changes, Vue doesn't update the view because it is no longer the `<plasmid>` tag but an svg component.

I therefore need to re-render the component, my attempts to use `$forceUpdate()` have not worked.

Comment: "it is no longer the <plasmid> tag but an svg component" What does this mean? Can you show your code?

Comment: @thanksd sure, I tried to make it as explicit as possible: https://pastebin.com/KPjiTuDQ

Comment: Could you append the svg to the plasmid tag rather than replace/transform it?

Comment: @jaredsk not easily from what I've glanced, ideally I would be able to ask Vue.js to re-render that component, since it would re-generate the appropriate markup before being rendered by the external library

Answer (score 2):

If `<plasmid>` is your Vue component, inside it you should have a method that draws your svg graphics, let's call it `drawPlasmid()`. Now, you have to trigger this method whenever `sequenceLength` is changed. You can do it either with an event handler:

```
<template>
  <div @change-sequence-length=changeSequenceLength"></div>
</template>

<script>
  methods: {
    changeSequenceLength(e) {
      this.drawPlasmid(e.detail.sequenceLength)
    }
    drawPlasmid(sequenceLength) {
      // Render svg graphics
    }
  }
<script>
```

or a watcher:

```
watch: {
  sequenceLength: function() {
    this.drawPlasmid(this.sequenceLength)
  }
}
```

I hope this puts you on the right track.

Comment: @asselinpaul this is about what I had in mind. Try using a watcher.